# Why does my image only accept some src attributes and reject others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image tag with an empty src attribute that displays a prompt() asking for a link when the user clicks on it. Once the user enters the link, I want the browser to display "LINK INVALID" if the image is invalid (the link is not on the internet), show the image to the user if it is valid (the link leads to an existent image on the internet), or display "ENTER IMAGE HERE" if the user clicked "X" or "Cancel" and also by default.

Here is my code so far:

**HTML**

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<img id="my-image" onclick="showImage()" src="" alt="ENTER IMAGE LINK">
```

**JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY**

```js
$(function() {
    $("#my-image").resizable();
});

function showImage() {
    let imageLink = prompt('Enter Image Link (Click "Cancel" to remove image):');


    if (imageLink === null) {
        document.getElementById("my-image").alt = 'ENTER IMAGE LINK';
        document.getElementById("my-image").removeAttribute("src");
        return;
    }

    $('img[id$=my-image]').load(imageLink, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status === "error") {
            document.getElementById("my-image").alt = 'LINK INVALID';
            document.getElementById("my-image").removeAttribute("src");
            return;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("my-image").alt = 'LINK VALID';
            $("#my-image").attr('src', imageLink);
        }
    });
}
```

The code works just fine as it is, but there is only one problem, the browser only accepts certain links. What I mean by that is that some links get successfully displayed, while others are replaced with the alt attribute "LINK INVALID", even though I copied and pasted them directly from the web and got them to work in another test script that simply displays the image without changing the alt attribute. I have tinkered with this code a lot and I am fairly sure that this line is what is causing my problem:

```js
document.getElementById("my-image").removeAttribute("src")
```

But I don't really understand what's wrong with it, therefore I don't know how to fix it.

The following link is invalid:
https://www.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/styles/article_main_large/public/cc_iStock-478639870_16x9.jpg?itok=1-jMc4Xv

This one is valid:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/CabbageTreeKaihoka.jpg/1200px-CabbageTreeKaihoka.jpg

Comment: you haven't shown a single link that results in "link invalid" - so, I'm guessing you're doing *something wrong™*

Comment: @Jaromanda X, I've updated my post

Comment: use the browser developer tools console/network ... anything in there telling you WHAT the error is? (firefox will show `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/styles/articl…main_large/public/cc_iStock-478639870_16x9.jpg?itok=1-jMc4Xv. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

Comment: the TL;DR is - the sites that fail do so because they don't allow you to use their resources like that - see CORS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting bitten by the AJAX same-origin policy. `.load()` uses AJAX, which is restricted to the same domain unless the server explicitly allows cross-origin requests. This policy doesn't apply to image `src`.

The way around this is to just set the `src` attribute of the image to the new URL, and handle the `error` event that occurs if loading the image fails.

```js
$("#my-image").on("error", function() {
  $(this).removeAttr("src").attr("alt", "LINK INVALID");
});

function showImage() {
  let imageLink = prompt('Enter Image Link (Click "Cancel" to remove image):');
  if (imageLink === null) {
    $("#my-image").removeAttr("src").attr("alt", "ENTER LINK");
    return;
  }
  $('#my-image').attr('src', imageLink);
}

$("#show").click(showImage);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="my-image" alt="ENTER LINK">
<button id="show">Enter link</button>
```